# Docker command won't connect to docker

Tags: docker

Latest Mac Sierra 10.12.5 and latest stable CE Docker for Mac Version 17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661).  Docker says server is "started" but when I do command line 'docker info' I get the following error after a long delay:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://192.168.99.101:2376. Is
the docker daemon running?
```

Comment: Your trying to access the docker daemon on the TCP socket on port 2376.  
Looks like your docker daemon is not listening on this socket.  
Take a look at your `dockerd` process to check on which socket it's listening.

Comment: Thanks, a 'ps -eaf|grep dockerd' shows nothing.  Doing 'docker --help' takes 30 seconds to respond, which I find strange and possibly a clue to what's going on (unless even 'help' requires a connection to the daemon.)

Answer (score 0):

The `192.168.99.101` address sounds like something from Docker Machine. It sounds like you probably have exported legacy environment variables overriding the defaults. Check with:

```
env | grep DOCKER
```

If there are some variables listed, unset them using `unset` like:

```
unset DOCKER_HOST
```

If this is the case then you probably have something in your shell profile loading these environment variables (something like `eval $(docker-machine env default`).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was several DOCKER env variables in my bash_profile, evidently from an old installation.  After commenting those out, things seem to work.  Got the suggestion from here: https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/302